# Graph calculus homework

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

My teacher gave us a set of exercises for homework. I've been struggling with this one.

[image: The graph of the function <span class=]$f$">

The graph of the function $f$ shown above consists of three line segments. If $g$ is the function defined by  $g(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$ , then what is $g(−1)$

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for the welcoming message, @AlainRemillard. Jam's answer has already helped me :)

Comment: Be aware that the integral's bounds are in reverse order (the upper bound is smaller) so the sign of the integral is flipped. I.e., $\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{blue}{-1}}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=-\int_{\color{blue}{-1}}^{\color{red}{0}}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: Negative area? Does that make sense, @Jam?

Comment: @mephistopheles An integral is the **signed** area of a curve, i.e., it takes the sign of the function into account. In places where the curve stays above the $x$-axis, the integral is positive but if the curve is below the $x$-axis, the integral would be negative. This is true even when the bounds are in the right order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the geometric meaning of an integral? How would you describe the shape determined by the function in the desired area and how would you turn this into a geometry problem?

Comment: Great! Thank you so much :)